# Калифорнийский университет в Лос-Анджелесе — с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли писать с прописной буквы названия американских университетов такого типа: University of Michigan, University of California, Los Angeles и так далее.

```
Я поступил в (У/у)ниверситет Мичигана.
Я поступил в (К/к)алифорнийский университет в Лос-Анджелесе.
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я поступил в университет Мичигана (со строчной - [не один же в штате университет](http://collegemvd.by/us/Michigan.html)), но

[Мичиганский университет](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82) и [Университет штата Мичиган](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82_%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD) (это их полные официальные название, просят не путать).

Калифорнийский университет в Лос-Анджелесе (конкретно - первое слово с прописной).

---

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=1789):

> В названиях государственных учреждений, общественных, профессиональных
>   и т. п. организаций первое слово (и все имена собственные) пишется с
>   прописной буквы: *Верховный суд Российской Федерации, Министерство
>   обороны Российской Федерации, Международная демократическая федерация
>   женщин, Международный союз молодёжи, Итальянская конфедерация
>   профсоюзов трудящихся, Народная палата Индии, Верховный суд США,
>   Московская патриархия.*
>
> ***В названиях научных учреждений и учебных заведений первое слово (и все имена собственные)*** пишется с прописной буквы:
>
> *Российская академия наук, Академия медицинских наук Российской
>   Федерации, Московский государственный университет им. М. В.
>   Ломоносова, Российская академия театрального искусства, Московский
>   государственный институт международных отношений, Всесоюзный
>   государственный институт кинематографии. Центральный
>   научно-исследовательский институт технологии машиностроения,
>   Воронежский государственный университет, Саратовский государственный
>   педагогический институт, Московский техникум лёгкой промышленности,
>   Московский педагогический колледж, Центральная музыкальная школа при
>   Московской государственной консерватории им. П. И. Чайковского,
>   Московское училище живописи, ваяния и зодчества.*

[Аналогичное правило действует при написании иностранных учебных заведений: Бостонский универ­ситет, Нью-Йоркский университет, Кембриджский университет, Пекинский университет, Токийский тех­нологический институт.](http://www.znaew.ru/index.php/govorim-i-pishem-pravilno/5241-kak-pravilno-pishutsya-nazvaniya-vysshikh-uchebnykh-zavedenij)